# How can I unwrap t.co links with Python?

Tags: python, twitter

I want to expand t.co short links into a full URL. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use Twitter's API.  Each tweet has [a JSON representation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid); reading [JSON from Python is straightforward](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

One of the [entities contained in the JSON](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities) is `expanded_url`, defined as "The fully resolved URL".

Comment: Thanks! I haven't checked Twitter API changes since t.co was created actually. That definitely will help.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way in python2 is to use [`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen):

```
tco_url = "http://t.co/whatever"
req = urllib2.urlopen(tco_url)
print req.url
```

will print the URL `tco_url` finally resolves to, after following all redirects.

Answer (score 7):

Using [requests](http://python-requests.org), you could write:

```
>>> import requests
>>> print(requests.get("http://t.co/UVgwaemZ").url)
http://paper.li/vascoda/vascoda-partner
```